# sorting messages, obj comparison is greyed out and is asking to be replaced with "comparator.comparing", which doesn't work

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

[image][image]this code here, after the sort method, the obj1 and obj2 comparison is greyed out, and the editor suggests to convert it into `Comparator.comparing`, which does not do the job and the chats of the reciever stays as a sticky constant, while sender chats keep going above it,

[image: the database]

````
```   
Collections.sort(chatMessages,
                    (obj1, obj2) -> obj1.dateObject.compareTo(obj2.dateObject));
            if(count == 0) {
                chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

} else {
}
````

```
//new lines of code that seem to work
chatMessages.sort(Comparator.comparing(obj -> obj.dateObject));
            if(count == 0) {
                chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and the last part, to be more specific with change of events, and use notifyDataSetChanged() as a last resort.

[image]

Comment: What's the type of dateObject field and collection chatMessages?

Comment: Why don't you perform a query to get the messages alredy sorted?

Comment: import java.util.Date;

public String senderId, receiverId, message, dateTime;
    public Date dateObject;

this is what i have in chatMessages adapter....

Comment: @AlexMamo, i dunno, i mean i went this direction...but please tell me how would i go about it?   also i am using Firestore NoSQL database

Comment: i hope this pastebin is helpful, resides the whole part of the code 
https://pastebin.com/Qj9cX0MN

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact documents you want to get and the exact order.

Comment: i have edited the code, and seems to fetch me the desired result now, could you please check once, if this is the right approach, compared to the old one.